# How can you use multiple directories for static files in an aspnet core app?

Tags: asp.net-core

By default, the wwwroot directory can host static files. However, in some scenarios, it might be ideal to have two directories for static files. (For example, having webpack dump a build into one gitignored directory, and keeping some image files, favicon and such in a not-gitignored directory). Technically, this could be achieved by having two folders within the wwwroot, but it might organizationally preferable to have these folders at the root level. Is there a way to configure an aspnet core app to use two separate directories for static files?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just register `UseStaticFiles` twice:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "static"))
});
```

Now files will be found from wwwroot and static folders.

Comment:  Why does the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) never say *Just register UseStaticFiles twice*?

Comment: @zwcloud you made my day! 

Comment: @zwcloud It actually says that:
Serve files from multiple locations
UseStaticFiles and UseFileServer default to the file provider pointing at wwwroot. Additional instances of UseStaticFiles and UseFileServer can be provided with other file providers to serve files from other locations.

Comment: Do not forget to specify RequestPath property for StaticFileOptions to the desired URL for your static files (also mentioned in the docs).

Answer (score 3):

Registering `UseStaticFiles` twice won't solve it for `MapFallbackToFile`

An alternative approach.

```
// Build the different providers you need
var webRootProvider = 
  new PhysicalFileProvider(builder.Environment.WebRootPath);

var newPathProvider = 
  new PhysicalFileProvider(
   Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, @"Other"));

// Create the Composite Provider
var compositeProvider = 
  new CompositeFileProvider(webRootProvider, newPathProvider);

// Replace the default provider with the new one
app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider = compositeProvider;
```

https://wildermuth.com/2022/04/25/multiple-directories-for-static-files-in-aspnetcore/