# How to dynamically serve static files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building a ASP.Net Core project which will be used as an online-help for my app and it will serve static files which will display in-app contextual help.

However, one requirement is that each customer can have his own customized help. If he doesn't it should fall back to the default help page.

So I create a WebApplication project as a start. I would need to create a Controller with just one action that receives 2 parameters (customerId, helpId).

Where should the static files be kept (under wwwroot or Pages)?

Comment: You could add two static file middleware to the pipeline. One for the optional client help, the other for the built in.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman An example code that I can follow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021715/how-can-you-use-multiple-directories-for-static-files-in-an-aspnet-core-app

Comment: Maybe don't serve static files? Instead store the info in the database (as HTML if you like, or just strings which can be embedded in a view template) and then use a controller action to select the help data from the database. Then you can obviously change the data per customer.

Comment: Here is the answer: 
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/conditionally-serve-files-statically-or-dynamically-with-httphandlers